# A fair coin is tossed until the first time that the same side appears twice in succession. Let N be the number of tosses required.

Tags: probability, statistics

A fair coin is tossed until the first time that the same side appears
twice in succession. Let N be the number of tosses required.

(a) Determine the probability mass function for N.

(b) Let A be the event that N is even and B be the event that N $\le$ 6.
Evaluate Pr{A}, Pr{B}, and Pr{AB}.

For (a) I got $$P(N=n)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$

For (b), I'm not so sure.

Comment: the number of tossed required cannot be determined, at most we can define the expectation of tosses required or the probability that in $n$ tosses the event happen.

Comment: @Masacroso That is indeed what is being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) To obtain $N=n$ we must have some coin flip followed by $n-2$ alternating flips, then one repeated flip.   So indeed *for an unbiased coin*, $\mathsf P(N=n)= 2^{1-n}\mathbf 1_{n\in[2;\infty)\cap\Bbb N}$

(b) $~~A$ is the event that $N$ is even so $\mathsf P(A) ~{= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathsf P(N=2k)\\= 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty 4^{-k}}$

$\qquad B$ is the event that $N\leq 6$ so $\mathsf P(B) = \sum_{n=2}^6 \mathsf P(N=n)$

$\qquad AB$ is the event ...